# Python yaml writes empty file if dump fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, yaml, pyyaml

I have the following snippet:

```py
if file:
    try:
        with open(file, 'w') as outfile:
            try:
                yaml.dump(self.dataset_configuration, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
                self.dataset_configuration_file = file
            except yaml.YAMLError as ex:
                _logger.error("An error has occurred while trying to save dataset configuration:\n", ex)
    except OSError as ex:
        _logger.error(f"Unable to create file '{self.dataset_configuration_file}' "
                      f"to persist the dataset configuration\n", ex)
```

I've noticed that sometimes, if the object cannot be picked/serialized, then the `dump` method would fail and write an empty file. Is there a quick option to not overwrite the opened file if it already exists or do I have to make a copy of the file, and then if the `dump` operation fails, I would restore the file?

The above, as per @martineau's suggestion, can be also rewritten as:

```py
if file:
    serialized_object_string = ''
    try:
        serialized_object_string = yaml.dump(self.dataset_configuration, default_flow_style=False)
    except yaml.YAMLError as ex:
        _logger.error("An error has occurred while trying to save dataset configuration:\n", ex)
    if serialized_object_string:
        try:
            with open(file, 'w') as output_file:
                output_file.write(serialized_object_string)
                self.dataset_configuration_file = file
        except OSError as ex:
            _logger.error(f"Unable to create file '{self.dataset_configuration_file}' "
                          f"to persist the dataset configuration\n", ex)
```

In this case, first a string representation of the object would be created, and then it would be written to file if it isn't empty or failed to serialize. Would there be a significant penalty for not going through a `Stream` object? What happens if the string representation is very big? Is there a "native" way to do it the above in one operation?

Comment: `yaml.dump()` accepts an optional second argument, which must be an open text or binary file. If it's not provided the document produced will be returned. This implies that you could postpone opening and writing the file until after `dump()` returns without error.

Comment: @martineau, I've updated the question slightly.

Comment: It's probably faster and it will use more memory, but that likely won't matter unless the output is `really` huge, like 100's of millions of bytes. You should be able answer most of these question yourself with a little testing and benchmarking.

Comment: I think you should write out the answer as it is really you who provided it.

Comment: Quirky: Thanks for offering, but that's not necessary. Consider it a gift and pay it forward, `;¬)`

Comment: Merci, <3 and give the answer some love too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above, as per @martineau's suggestion, can be also rewritten as:

```py
if file:
    serialized_object_string = ''
    try:
        serialized_object_string = yaml.dump(self.dataset_configuration, default_flow_style=False)
    except yaml.YAMLError as ex:
        _logger.error("An error has occurred while trying to save dataset configuration:\n", ex)
    if serialized_object_string:
        try:
            with open(file, 'w') as output_file:
                output_file.write(serialized_object_string)
                self.dataset_configuration_file = file
        except OSError as ex:
            _logger.error(f"Unable to create file '{self.dataset_configuration_file}' "
                          f"to persist the dataset configuration\n", ex)
```

It works, although I was hoping for more of an "integrated" solution.